# Optional (selective) Flow checks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

Is there a way to just execute Flow checks for code where a type declaration is available?

There is a way to enable checks per file (`// @flow` in header), but once this set, all parts of the code need type declarations (otherwise an error is logged like "`108:10  error  parameter transformer:  Missing annotation` "). I'd like to start adding type declarations continuously and only when there is a real worth of it.

Answer (score 3):

Flow annotations are required only on exported functions.
So you can add `// @flow` at the beginning of the file and provided all exported function have an annotated signature, you can skip all the others until you deem it necessary.

If you're in a rush, you can always annotate your exported functions with `any`

```
// @flow

function someFunction(a: number): string {
  return a.toString();
}

export function someExportedFunction(bar: any) {
  return bar;
}
```

or use the `$FlowFixMe` comment, e.g.

```
// @flow

function someFunction(a: number): string {
  return a.toString();
}

// $FlowFixMe
export function someExportedFunction(bar) {
  return bar;
}
```

Up to version 0.39 you can also use `// @flow weak`, although [it will be removed soon](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/3316).